# Team Foundation - querying user stories by tags

Tags: tfs

I'm trying to create a query in the web front-end of Team Foundation Server 2012 to show me user stories with a specific tag but the 'tag' option isn't available from the drop down field list.

I'm trying to use it for all my ideas for our software which may or may not be used within the backlog thus creating an 'ideas' query.

Can anyone help or suggest a better way of achieving this?

Comment: This applies to TFS2013 as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it - as **gbjbaanb** and **Khh** have confirmed - you can't query on a free type box but you can use the filter option on the backlog page.

[image]

Comment: here, have an upvote! Thanks for highlighting the filter button. I've never noticed that small, gray icon before :)

Answer (score 4):

As [gbjbaanb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18467585/team-foundation-querying-user-stories-by-tags/18467811#18467811) said using the query window is not possible, only creating a query and than use the filter on the result of the query.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dn132606.aspx) says:

> Q: Can I add a tag to my query?
>
> A: No
> You can filter a work item query, but you cannot add a tag through the query editor.

You can use the tagging filter in the backlog and Features view (picture taken from tfspreview).

[image: tagging filter]

Answer (score 2):

IIRC you can't use any free-text fields for searching, eg, you can't use the description field either.

If you know what the tags are, you can create a list and search on that.